# How can I return a generic object, that also has a generic type?

Tags: java, generics

Say I have a collection ( **do not focus** on the **Collection interface** please ) object of any generic type. Set, TreeSet, ArrayList, SortedSet, etc ...

Then I want a method similar to this pseudo one ( which is flawed ):

```
private static <T,V> T<V> returnPlease(T<V> obj) {
    return obj;
}
```

But now I get "Type T does not have Type parameters"

That is, I want to access the subgeneric type as well.

I am aware of the more common way:

```
private static <T> T returnPlease(T obj) {
    return obj;
}
```

Only I want the method to access what type of the TreeSet it is as well.
Not only the TreeSet, but also what generic version it is using, in this case String.

How is my syntax wrong? Is this not possible?

**================== EDIT FOR MORE CLARITY ==================**

```
static interface AnInterface<Return, Param1> {
    public Return method(Param1 obj1);
}

private static <T,V> AnInterface<V, V> returnPlease(T<V> obj) {
    return new AnInterface<V, V>() {
        public V method(V v) {
            // Do something
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

I hope this helps to understand a little bit more ...

Comment: What's wrong with the simple `<T>` version? It should return the fully typed class.

Comment: Haskell's type system is powerful enough to express this, but not Java's.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't make sense. So you'd be O.K. with a `Comparable<V>` *or* a `Set<V>` *or* a `ThreadLocal<V>`, even though the only thing they have in common is that they each have *some* type parameter?

You wrote "do not focus on the Collection interface please", but I think that's really the only option; you need to have some sort of specific meaningful requirement, e.g. "implements `Collection<V>`", in order for the type parameter to be meaningful. For example, you can write:

```
static interface AnInterface<Return, Param1> {
    public Return method(Param1 obj1);
}

private static <V, T extends Collection<? extends V>> AnInterface<V, V> returnPlease(T obj) {
    return new AnInterface<V, V>() {
        public V method(V v) {
            // Do something
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

and Java will actually be smart enough to infer both `T` and `V` from the type of argument that you pass, so you can write e.g.:

```
AnInterface<String, String> x = returnPlease(new TreeSet<String>());
```